# Checkbox In Listview + vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox

Can anyone help me on how to do this..

I have a ListView with Checkboxes in vb.net and what I want to do is when the user check the checkbox, the program ignore the response of the user in checking the checkbox, instead it leaves the checkbox uncheck..

This concern is uses for may validation..

Thanks for your positive response regarding this..

Comment: Quick question... Why are you using Checkboxes in your ListBox if you dont want the user to be able to check them? is it a readonly list?

Comment: I have to use listview with checkbox for the user to choose what data were going to save into the database.. also i have to disabled that checkbox if the rows have an error to not be able to save in the database..

Answer (score 0):

Edit, removed untested solution.

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCheck
    e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked
End Sub
```

Comment: I already try it, but I doesn't work.. I also try in selectedIndexChange event but still not working..

Comment: I missed that there was both a Checked and a Check event, I think my previous idea might have worked if it had been in the Checked event instead, but either way, my edited solution is much neater.

Comment: Ill also try that but that code was never allow the user to check another rows.. I already have a nested statement but still not working.. Did you have an any idea?

Comment: Well, the answer above does work as far as I understand the question. If rather than just keeping them all unchecked you want to keep them in whatever value they currently are, e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue might work. And if you only want to disable certain rows you should be able to use e.Index I'd have thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim lastUndo As Boolean = False
Private Sub thisListView_ItemChecked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles thisListView.ItemChecked
    If lastUndo Then
        lastUndo = False
    Else
        If thisListView.Focused Then
            lastUndo = True
            e.Item.Checked = Not e.Item.Checked
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This example allows the listview checkboxes to be checked or unchecked by some other control or operation, however when the user clicks on a checkbox in the listview the handler will undo the changed checkbox state, i.e. the user will not be able to change the checkbox(es) state for this list view.